# Perl local libraries - Sybase

Tags: perl, module, local, root, sybase

I'm going to build a extremly small script for dumping a Sybase database in perl. The problem is that Perl doesn't come with preinstalled Sybase-support. I don't have access to the servers root so I can't install any packages and I can't reach the perl-folder. The server is not configured for internet access so I have to deliver the packages "manually" thorugh FTP.

So, my question is if there are any easy ways of doing this. The only library I need is DBI::Sybase or Sybase standalone (maybe I haven't done my research enough and doesn't even need this much?) which means I would love to just be able to put the .pm file there, loading it through
use localModule
and then run my small script.
The solution has to work on both Red hat and Solaris if I understood my supervisor correctly.

Best regards

Comment: Sybase was a company not a database.  Please specify the Sybase product, and version you are referring to.  It makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You don't need root access to install modules in Perl. Google for `locallib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are primarily concerned with dumping the database, and not data retrieval and manipulation, you could probably get by without having to use `DBI::Sybase` or other perl module that is not preinstalled.

Without more details, it's hard to be very specific, but here's the overview.  Your perl script can execute some SQL scripts which can dump the databases.

You can either put the list of databases you wish to dump in a config file (or env file), or you can generate it dynamically by calling `isql` using the `-b` option to suppress headers, and `nocount` to suppress footers, and store the output in an array.

Once you have the list of databases, just loop them, running another `isql` command to dump each database.